# Django South - Create Not Null ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I have a Model

```
class Mystery(models.Model):
    first = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    second = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    third = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
```

I added the player ForeignKey but when I try to migrate it using South it seems that I can't create this whith a null=False. I have this message :

> The field 'Mystery.player' does not have a default specified, yet is
>   NOT NULL. Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
>   value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
>    1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
>    2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now

I use this command :

> manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto

Thanks a lot !

Comment: If your database already contains Mystery objects, then south must know, what value put into `player` field, because it cannot be blank. One possible solution: choose 2. Specify a one-off ... and then enter 1. So all of your existing Mystery objects will now point to Player with pk = 1. Then you can change (if needed) this in admin.

Comment: I'll write it as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option is to create a [data migration](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations) before adding the ForeignKey, in which you create a new Player instance with a specific id. Be sure that that id does not exist previously in your database.

1.Create the data migration file

```
$ ./manage.py datamigration myapp add_player
Created 00XX_add_player.py
```

2.Edit the *forwards* and *backwards* methods of the file:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    orm['myapp.Player'].objects.create(name=u'Very misterious player', id=34)

def backwards(self, orm):
    # Haven't tested this one yet
    orm['myapp.Player'].objects.filter(id=34).delete()
```

3.Add the ForeignKey to your Mistery class and migrate the schema again. It will ask for the default value to your data migration id, in this example, 34.

```
 $ ./manage.py schemamigration --auto myapp
 ? The field 'Mistery.player' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
 ? Please select a choice: 2
 ? Please enter Python code for your one-off default value.
 ? The datetime module is available, so you can do e.g. datetime.date.today()
 >>> 34
 + Added field player on myapp.Mistery
Created 0010_auto__add_field_mistery_player.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate myapp
```

4.Finally run the migrate command and it will execute the migrations in sequential order, inserting the new Player and updating all the Mistery rows with the reference to your new Player.

Comment: Please don't do this. This solution could easily bite you in the future when someone else runs the migration. What if they already have an object with ID for example? In general, choosing an arbitrary ID and putting that into a migration should probably be considered a very bad practice. Please see my suggested solution.

Answer (score 11):

This is best accomplished in 3 migrations.

Step 1. Create the new model and allow player to be null: `player = models.ForeignKey(Player, null=True)`

Step 2. Run `./manage.py schemamigration <app> --auto`

Step 3. Run `./manage.py datamigration <app> set_default_players`

Step 4. Update forwards and backwards in `<app>/migrations/<number>_set_default_players.py` to use whatever logic you like for setting the default player. Ensure that every `Mystery` object has a value for `player`.

Step 5. Update the `Mystery` model so that `player` has `null=False`.

Step 6. Run `./manage.py schemamigration <app> --auto`

Step 7. Run `./manage.py migrate <app>`

Comment: This answer seems better than the accepted one. The only change I'd suggest is that "null=True" should be "blank=True" if the intent is to allow nulls. (intuitive? no.)

Comment: Could you explain a little more why you think this? `blank` only affects validation and, so, shouldn't be applicable for the brief period the field is nullable. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#blank

Comment: My bad. Caught once again by the severely broken django documentation. `null=True` is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If your database already contains Mystery objects, then south must know, what value put into `player` field, because it cannot be blank.

One possible solution:

choose

```
    2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
```

and then enter 1. So all of your existing Mystery objects will now point to Player with pk = 1. Then you can change (if needed) this in admin page.