# Django 1.6: One to Many relationship issue with south

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-south

In need of some dire help with setting up relationships in my django model and views.

Just wanted to say **thank you!** before anyone takes a deep dive below!

Working on an application were I have a One to Many relationship where I have many Products and a few particular products will be related to only one Website.

One of the biggest problems am experiencing is when I try to add a foreign key to my **Website Model** I get this error:

```
 ? The field 'Product.website' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
```

I tried to use this solution here:
[Django South - Create Not Null ForeignKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210272/django-south-create-not-null-foreignkey/22617012#22617012)

But to no avail, didnt know what to do after Step #4 and I just got lost regardless.

## Models.py in my product_extend app

**Product Model:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    The product structure for the application, the products we scrap from sites will model this and save directly into the tables.
    """

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name=_('Name'), null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = CurrencyField( verbose_name=_('Unit price') )
    product_slug_url = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True)
    product_category = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    product_img = models.ImageField('Product Image', upload_to='product_images', null=True, blank=True) 
    product_website_url = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True) 
    product_website_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    
    #For Admin Purposes, to keep track of new and old items in the database by administrative users
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Date added'))
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Last modified') )

    #For Admin Purposes, to make sure an item is active by administrative users
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Active') )

    # Foreign Key
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, null=True, related_name='website_to_product')
```

**Website Model**

```
class Website(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    website_slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('Website Slug'), unique=True)
    site_logo = models.ImageField('Websites Logo', upload_to='website_logo_images', null=True, blank=True) 

    menswear = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Menswear'))
    womenswear = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Womenswear'))
    

    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Active'))
```

## Edit

I shortened this question in an effort to make it more comprehensible and split the second part as another question:

[Django 1.6: Displaying a particular models Objects in another template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27485242/django-1-6-displaying-a-particular-models-objects-on-another-template-page)

Comment: Are u using django 1.7 ?

Comment: You clearly have two quite separate problems here: one about how to add an FK in migrations, and one about how to construct the URLs. Please split them up into separate questions.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for that note! I split the question in two as you recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Is it right to say that when you do the migration, both Product and Websites already exist in models.py? If that is the case, a workaround would be to enter a random value for this

```
     ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
```

Or you may for the time being set the null to be true. Then after you created the foreign key and added the key values for the existing rows. You can re-set it to be false. Then run the migration process as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22617012/2774853:

```
    Step 6. Run ./manage.py schemamigration <app> --auto

    Step 7. Run ./manage.py migrate <app>
```

Hope it helps.