# Django 1.6: Displaying a particular models Objects in another template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Working on an application were I have a One to Many relationship where I have many Products and a few particular products will be related to only one Website.

On my Home page is where I display my listed sites from my **Website Model** I would like to show products for when the user clicks on anyone of the slugs on my Homepage the are redirected to go into a product page ( another template ) where I have all of the objects related from my **Product Model** to that particular website to display only.

**Here is a User flow of my situation**

Homepage --> click on website ('/browse/website_slug') ---> Go To --> Product page (filled with only Product Objects from related clicked slug)

## Models.py in my product_extend app

**Product Model:**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    """
    The product structure for the application, the products we scrap from sites will model this and save directly into the tables.
    """

    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name=_('Name'), null=True, blank=True)
    product_price = CurrencyField( verbose_name=_('Unit price') )
    product_slug_url = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True)
    product_category = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)
    product_img = models.ImageField('Product Image', upload_to='product_images', null=True, blank=True) 
    product_website_url = models.URLField(max_length=200,  null=True, blank=True) 
    product_website_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True)

    #For Admin Purposes, to keep track of new and old items in the database by administrative users
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Date added'))
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_('Last modified') )

    #For Admin Purposes, to make sure an item is active by administrative users
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Active') )

    # Foreign Key
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, null=True, related_name='website_to_product')
```

**Website Model**

```
class Website(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    website_slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('Website Slug'), unique=True)
    site_logo = models.ImageField('Websites Logo', upload_to='website_logo_images', null=True, blank=True) 

    menswear = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Menswear'))
    womenswear = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name=_('Womenswear'))


    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('Active'))
```

## Views in my product_extend app

**view.py**

```
 class ProductView(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'product_extend/_productlist.html'
    # queryset = ProductExtend.objects.filter(id=1)
    model = Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class WebsiteView(ListView):

context_object_name = 'home'
template_name = 'homepage.html'
queryset = Website.objects.order_by('name')
model = Website

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(WebsiteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    return context
```

## Templates

**Homepage.html**

```
  {% for object in home %}
        <li class="page_tiles-home home-website-reveal"> 
            <a href="browse/website_slug" data-title="{{object.name}}" data-description="{{object.description}}">
                <img alt="{{object.name}}" src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{object.site_logo}}" />
            </a> 
        </li>  
    {% endfor %}
```

**Product.html**

```
{% for object in product_list %}
    <li class="col n-4">
        <figure class="rollover site">
            <div class="scrap-likes"><span class="icon-heart"></span></div>
            <img src="{{object.product_img}}" width="470" height="700">
           <!--  <div class="scrap-from"> Scrapped from:<a class="scrap-site" target="_blank" href="{{object.product_website_url}}">{{object.product_website_name}}</a></div> -->
            <div class="scrap-designer"> Scrapped from: <a class="scrap-site" target="_blank" href="{{object.product_website_url}}">{{object.product_website_name}}</a></div>
            <div class="scrap-title">{{object.product_name }}, <span class="scrap-price">${{object.product_price}}</span></div>
            <a class="scrap-buy" target="_blank" href="{{object.product_slug_url}}">View Item</a>
        </figure>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

## Urls

**my apps  urls.py**

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
     url(r"^$", WebsiteView.as_view(), name="home"),
     url(r'^browse/', include('product_extend.urls')),
    )
```

**my apps product_extend urls.py**

```
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
     ??? No clue what to put ???
   )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this in **product_extend urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<website_slug>[\w]+)$', ProductView.as_view(), name='products_list'),
)
```

Then in `ProductView` override the `get_queryset` method to use the `website_slug` for filtering the queryset:

```
class ProductView(ListView):

    context_object_name = 'product_list'
    template_name = 'product_extend/_productlist.html'
    # queryset = ProductExtend.objects.filter(id=1)
    model = Product

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(ProductView, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(website__website_slug__exact=self.kwargs['website_slug'])
```

Answer (score 0):

after reading twice, think what you want is:

```
url(r'^product/website/(?P<slug>)$', "your_view_to_peform_product_search_for_slug_website_here"),
```

and in your view "HTML"

```
href="product/website/{{ website.slug }}"
```

something like this...